# TypeError ClassName on JavasScript Slider

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a slideshow using JavaScript, however I keep running into the following error.
I receive an type error Cannot read property 'className' of undefined, upon clicking the dots and the images aren't showing at all. Any idea what the problem might be?

```
index.html:293 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'className' of undefined
    at showSlides (index.html:293)
    at currentSlide (index.html:277)
    at HTMLSpanElement.onclick (index.html:219)
```

```
    <section>
        <h2 class="title">Section Title.</h2>
        <div class="slider-container">
            <div class="slider">
                <div class="slides fade">
                    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1511376777868-611b54f68947?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80">
                    <div class="slider-text">Slider text</div>
                </div>

                <div class="slides fade">
                    <img src="https://unsplash.com/photos/n31x0hhnzOs">
                    <div class="slider-text">Slider text</div>
                </div>

                <div class="slides fade">
                    <img src="https://unsplash.com/photos/nC6CyrVBtkU">
                    <div class="slider-text">Slider text</div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="slider-marks">
                <span class="mark" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
                <span class="mark" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
                <span class="mark" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

```
<script>
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

// Thumbnail image controls
function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("slides");
  var marks = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < marks.length; i++) {
      marks[i].className = marks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  marks[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have an html element with class "dot", but your code is looking for it:

`var marks = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");`

This function is returning `undefined`, so later on in your program you're trying to use marks as an array when really it is `undefined`, which causes an error.

Updated your code so it kinda works (not sure what you're trying to do, but based on what you have, this might be it):

https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-microservice-xeek6?file=/index.html:0-1974

Comment: that fixed the marks, I can now click on them however the images still aren't being displayed?

Comment: I've updated my answer with your request. You might wanna remove the ifs